# I need help using count for a query

Tags: mysql, join, aggregate-functions

i need to select A list showing the customer id, title, first name and surname of each customer who has hired a car, sorted alphabetically by customer surname together with a count of the number of bookings each of them has placed.

I've done the first part but not sure where to put count for the number of bookings placed.

Here are the tables are

```
create table customer
(customer_id  char(4) primary key not null,
customer_sname varchar (30) not null,
customer_fname varchar (30) not null,
customer_title varchar (6) not null,
customer_address1 varchar (35) not null,
customer_address2 varchar (35) null,
customer_postcode varchar (25) null,
customer_phone varchar (30) null,
customer_email varchar (40) null,
customer_di varchar (40) not null)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table car_booking
(booking_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT primary key not null,
car_id char (4) not null,
customer_id char (4)  not null,
hire_sdate date not null,
hire_edate date not null)
engine=innodb
```

I have done this

```
select customer_id, customer_title, Customer_fname, customer_sname
from customer
where customer_id in
(select customer_id from car_booking )
order by customer_sname asc
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will require the use of an aggregate function (COUNT), a GROUP BY clause, and a LEFT JOIN to the CAR_BOOKING table:

```
   SELECT c.customer_id, c.customer_title, c.customer_fname, c.customer_sname,
          COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) AS num_bookings
     FROM CUSTOMER c
LEFT JOIN CAR_BOOKING cb ON cb.customer_id = c.customer_id
 GROUP BY c.customer_id, c.customer_title, c.customer_fname, c.customer_sname
 ORDER BY c.customer_sname
```

Because there are columns not wrapped in an aggregate function like COUNT, those columns need to be defined in the GROUP BY clause.

I used a LEFT OUTER JOIN to the `CAR_BOOKINGS` table to return customers who do not have any bookings - these records will show zero as the value in the `num_booking` column.  You can omit the `LEFT` keyword in the query to return only customers & counts with bookings.  COALESCE is a standard function to convert a null value into a desired one - in this case, the count being null...

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, I'd use:

```
select c.customer_id,
       c.customer_title,           
       c.customer_fname,
       c.customer_sname,
       count (*)
  from cutomer c,
       car_booking cb
 where cb.customer_id = c.customer_id
 group by c.customer_id,
          c.customer_title,
          c.customer_fname,
          c.customer_sname
```

Not intimately familar with MySQL so it may play out a little differently, but that's the general idea.

Comment: The only reason I wouldn't use this syntax, is that it uses a theta join (i.e. an implicit join).

Answer (score 0):

```
select customer.customer_id, customer.customer_title, customer.customer_fname, customer.customer_sname, count(*) as Bookings
from customer JOIN car_booking ON customer.customer_id = car_booking.customer_id
GROUP BY customer.customer_id, customer.customer_title, customer.Customer_fname, customer.customer_sname
order by customer_sname asc
```

Comment: Thanks all, what i have are customer_id's that haven't booked car hire for some reason. it shows 6 cars that have been booked but when i run it now its showing most of the customer_id's. Any more ideas? Thanks

Comment: @skygirl: See the last paragraph of my answer to explain why you see the output you do, and how to change the query to correct it if necessary.

Comment: @skygirl Heh...I tend to screw this up w/o running a test case.  I think LEFT JOIN isn't correct here.  A plain JOIN should be correct.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks all :-) it worked ;-) Quick question isn't there a way i can just add on the count on my query i didn't complete? If not i'm happy with this

Comment: @skygirl From a performance perspective, I'm pretty sure that our answers are better than using a subquery. Do you have some specific need for a subquery that isn't evident here?

Comment: Hey, i'm very new to sql and learning it in uni, this is for my assignment. The reason for this is because i figured the first part myself and only wanted to add the count into my existing query. I;m happy with what you have suggested if i cannot do it any other way.